# Event emitter not catching the event

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

My **emitter.js** file

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var event = new EventEmitter();
export default event
```

I have another file in which I `emit` the event which I inside an api route

```
import Emitter from '../../config/emitter'

Emitter.emit('RIDING_STATUS', socketdriver)
```

And here I catch the event in **index.js**

```
import Emitter from '../config/emitter'

Emitter.on('RIDING_STATUS', async(data) => {
  console.log("Caught the event")
})
```

But problem is above event doesn't fire the `RIDING_STATUS` inside my **index.js**.

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a race condition.  The order may not be well defined, however you are firing an event before the listener is attached.

The following does not work (for example):

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var event = new EventEmitter();

event.emit('RIDING_STATUS');

//will never be triggered as the emit has already been fired.
event.on('RIDING_STATUS', async(data) => {
  console.log("Caught the event")
});
```

To make sure the event is emitted only after the listener is attached, put it in a setTimeout

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var event = new EventEmitter();

//Delay the emit event until after all setup code is complete
setTimeout(()=>event.emit('RIDING_STATUS'),0);

event.on('RIDING_STATUS', async(data) => {
  console.log("Caught the event")
});
```

The setTimeout ensures that all setup code is completed before the event emitter is fired.

So, to quote your code above, the middle block of code should be:

```
import Emitter from '../../config/emitter'

setTimeout(()=>Emitter.emit('RIDING_STATUS', socketdriver),0)
```